# SQL multiple insert and one group id

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I'm working on an MVC/NHibernate/SQL application where I need to insert multiple rows (generated dynamically) into the same table while giving them the same group id. 
Let's say I have the table with

```
fields(id[Identity], date, amount, group_Id)
```

How do I figure out a group_id to identify group entries?

As I understand, querying the max group id wouldn't be the solution as many users might access the application at the same time thus generate the same group id.
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You should say which db you're using, exact solution may vary from one to another.

Comment: Create the group, then you can select the last insert id (`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in mssql, there should be an equivalent) and then insert your other rows

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Then you should try the solution suggested in my last comment

Comment: Thanks rawk, I'll try scope_identity. I did try to create another table for the group but as I don't need to store anything else but group_id there I thought it would be pointless to add plus I have to deal with inserting data into two tables...

Comment: If you can insert the first record, then use the id of that as group_id, it could be useful to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the id of that first row. But otherwise I don't understand how SCOPE_IDENTITY() will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<Entity> group = ...;

var firstId = (int)session.Save(group[0]);
group[0].GroupId = firstId;

foreach(var e in group.Skip(1))
{
    e.GroupId = firstId;
    session.Save(e);
}
session.Flush();
```

this does work with almost every Id generation and database. It depends on the unique id of the first entry